# What does *map mean in python?

Tags: python

I know function `map`. It is used something like

`new_list = map(func, list)`

But what does `*map(func, list)` mean? It was used like

```
hands = set(best_hand(h) for h in itertools.product( *map(replacements, hand)))
```

Comment: In what context did you see it?  Perhaps as an argument for a function, so: `result = f(*map(other_f, l))`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: Yes, it was used  as an argument for a function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that the iterable returned from `map()` will be *unpacked* as arguments to the function.  That is, rather than calling the function and passing the iterable object as a single parameter, the individual elements of the iterable are passed as individual parameters.

An illustration of this technique:

```
>>> def foo(a, b, c): print "a:%s b:%s c:%s" % (a, b, c)
...
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> foo(*x)
a:1 b:2 c:3
```

But calling `foo()` without unpacking `x` means you are passing one argument where three are expected:

```
>>> foo(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

---

From the [Python 3 reference §6.3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls):

> If the syntax `*expression` appears in the function call, `expression` must evaluate to an iterable. Elements from this iterable are treated as if they were additional positional arguments ...